# Excel: I want a formula to display if a column contains "specific text"

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Please view screenshot

[image]

Orange table shows payments received/outstanding for a single month, in this case, Aug.

Green table shows total monthly payments, a good overview snapshot of how each month is doing.

I want a formula that can identify in column L for the month of Aug, any text that says "Outstanding"(it could be one cell or multiple cells). And if that is detected, then the green yearly snapshot will indicate "Outstanding" in the I column.

This will help me quickly find which months still have outstanding payments to look into.

Comment: Use COUNTIFS to check if exists.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
=IF(COUNTIF(A1,"*outstanding*"),"Outstanding","")
```

I am not seeing in your example how you choose your month; you may need to account for multiple conditions (`countifs()`) and use your overall range, e.g., if nothing has a december date, then it displays "Outstanding", whereas it sums for each december date if found date (`sumifs()`).

[image]